# Extend dataframe by adding start and end date and fill it with timestamps and NaN

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have got the following data:

```
                        data
timestamp
2012-06-01 17:00:00     9
2012-06-01 20:00:00     8
2012-06-01 13:00:00     9
2012-06-01 10:00:00     9
```

and would like to sort it descending by time, add a start and end date on top and bottom of the data, so that it looks like this:

```
                        data
timestamp
2012-06-01 00:00:00     NaN
2012-06-01 10:00:00     9
2012-06-01 13:00:00     9
2012-06-01 17:00:00     9
2012-06-01 20:00:00     8
2012-06-02 00:00:00     NaN
```

and finally I would like to extend the dataset to cover all hours from start to end in one hour steps, filling the dataframe with missing timestamps containing 'None'/'NaN' as data.
So far I have the following code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data':temperature, 'timestamp': pd.DatetimeIndex(timestamp)}, dtype=float)
df2.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({ 'timestamp': pd.Series([ts1, ts2]), 'data': [None, None]})
df3.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
print(df3)
merged = df3.append(df2)
print(merged)
```

with the following print outs:

```
df3:
                     data
timestamp                
2012-06-01 00:00:00     None
2012-06-02 00:00:00     None


merged:
                     data
timestamp                
2012-06-01 00:00:00     NaN
2012-06-02 00:00:00     NaN
2012-06-01 17:00:00     9
2012-06-01 20:00:00     8
2012-06-01 13:00:00     9
2012-06-01 10:00:00     9
```

I have tried:

```
merged = merged.asfreq('H')
```

but this returned an unsatisfying result:

```
                     data
2012-06-01 00:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 01:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 02:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 03:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 04:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 05:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 06:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 07:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 08:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 09:00:00   NaN
2012-06-01 10:00:00     9
```

Where is the rest of the dataframe? Why does it only contain data till the first valid value?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an empty dataframe with the timestamp index that you want and then do a left merge with your original dataset:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('2012-06-01','2012-06-02', freq='H'))
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'left')
df3 
Out[103]: 
                               timestamp  value
2012-06-01 00:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 01:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 02:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 03:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 04:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 05:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 06:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 07:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 08:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 09:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 10:00:00  2012-06-01 10:00:00      9
2012-06-01 11:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 12:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 13:00:00  2012-06-01 13:00:00      9
2012-06-01 14:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 15:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 16:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 17:00:00  2012-06-01 17:00:00      9
2012-06-01 18:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 19:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 20:00:00  2012-06-01 20:00:00      8
2012-06-01 21:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 22:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-01 23:00:00                  NaN    NaN
2012-06-02 00:00:00                  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: A bit late, but better late than never: thanks a lot for this, it helped my solving the issue!